# Как узнать максимальный объём оперативной памяти, который занимал процесс во время свой работы в linux?

Tags: linux

Например, имеется приложение, оно запускается из sh, выполняет свои функции и завершается. Как можно получить информацию о том, какое максимальное количество оперативной памяти было использовано программой?

Comment: Во время работы (до возврата из wait для этого процесса) см. [man 5 proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) /proc/[pid]/status VmHWM. После завершения (imho) вся такая статистика теряется

Answer (score 0):

С помощью atop - приложение логгирует состояние системы через определённые промежутки времени. По умолчанию 10 минут, значение можно изменить. Логи можно просмотреть как самой программой, в интерактивном режиме похожем на htop, top. Или с помощью atopsar - который идёт в комплекте и позволяет получить различные  отчёты.

Comment: Никакие приложения, записывающее метрики с определённой периодичностью, не могут показать максимальное потребление. Потому что может случайно оказаться так, что максимальное потребление было в момент между двумя измерениями, и приложение просто не успело это засечь

Comment: @andreymal, если atop умеет логировать (в т.ч. сохраняя файлы из /proc) по событию завершения процесса, то в VmHWM как раз будет искомая величина. Можно ли  сделать текой перехват в линуксе в принципе, не знаю, это уже другой вопрос